# How to refer to a class object by combining text and a number - C++

Tags: c++, class, object

is there a way to directly use the menuItem variable (which is an integer obviously) to put in the tft.print functions, so I don't have to use "if - else statements" like in the code below?

My idea is that it works kind of like this (I know that this code doesnt work - just the idea):

```cpp
tft.print(dmx(menuItem).channelName);
```

the "dmx" and "menuitem (1, 2,3...)" need to form a new word like in the code below. as example dmx1 or dmx2, which is a class object.

its basically adding a number to a text to form the object name, that has already been initialized. (dmx1, dmx2, dmx3 and so on...)

Here Is a snippet of my code:

```cpp
void print_keyboard() { 
      tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
      tft.drawRoundRect(11, 40, 220, 35,5, WHITE);
      tft.setCursor(15,50);
      tft.setTextColor(WHITE);
    
      if (menuItem == 1){
        tft.print(dmx1.channelName);
      }
      else if (menuItem == 2){
        tft.print(dmx2.channelName);
      }
      else if (menuItem == 3){
        tft.print(dmx3.channelName);
      }
      else if (menuItem == 4){
        tft.print(dmx4.channelName);
      }
      else if (menuItem == 5){
        tft.print(dmx5.channelName);
      }
      else if (menuItem == 6){
        tft.print(dmx6.channelName);
      }
   }
```

I am really a beginner in programming, and its hard to search for the right questions, as I don't know all the right expressions.

Comment: You might be looking for the concept of an array, or more generally a container.

Comment: What you're describing is called an "array" or a "vector". You have one name, and a small number. You combine them in a specific way, like `dmx[menuItem]` and get your value. So, make your dmx an array or a vector, problem solved! You just have to remember that array indexes start at 0 and not 1. That's really the only thing you'll need to change. See your C++ textbook for more info, examples and documentation.

Comment: i know what you mean with that. The thing is that I want to put "dmx" and "1" together to form "dmx1" (which is a class object that I already initialized). Or am I misunderstanding you? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Nope, C++ simply doesn't work this way. This is what arrays and vectors are for. And higher level objects in C++ also use the same syntax, so if -- for example -- one had to replace the vector with a map (for some reason) the code would remain unchanged, it would still read `dmx[menuItem]`!

Comment: The solution is to change your existing usage from `dmx1`, `dmx2` to `dmx[0]`, `dmx[1]`, so that you can also use `dmx[a_variable]` and `dmx[a + compilcated - expression]`, because there's no way to change them all to go the other direction.

Comment: @BenVoigt so I would create the objects like this?  `dmx[1]`, `dmx[2]` and so on. And then when i want to put the menuItem variable to choose from here: `dmx[menuItem]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers. I managed to bring it to work!

we can initialize an object array with parameterized constructors (This is done outside main loop, but can also be done inside):

```cpp
Dmx dmx[] = {Dmx("1","DMX CHANNEL 1"), Dmx("2","DMX CHANNEL 2"),Dmx("3","DMX CHANNEL 3"), Dmx("4","DMX CHANNEL 4"), Dmx("5","DMX CHANNEL 5"),
            Dmx("6","DMX CHANNEL 6"), Dmx("7","DMX CHANNEL 7"), Dmx("8","DMX CHANNEL 8"), Dmx("9","DMX CHANNEL 9"), Dmx("10","DMX CHANNEL 10")};
```

By then calling:

```cpp
tft.print(dmx[menuItem-1].channelName);
```

the menuItem variable is assigned to the index of dmx object. This way, when at menuItem 1 page, dmx[0] is called. Its not the cleanest solution. But it works.
Here is the code example but with the new changes:

```cpp
void print_keyboard() { 
  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  tft.drawRoundRect(11, 40, 220, 35,5, WHITE);
  tft.setCursor(15,50);
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);

  tft.print(dmx[menuItem-1].channelName);
  }
```